# Why is the while loop creating an infinite loop? Guessing 1 and 100

Tags: python

I created a while loop so I would keep on asking the user questions until they got the number right. But when a do a random number, for example, it either prints "Pick a higher number" or "pick a lower number" infinitely. Can someone help me out here.

```
from random import randint

answer = randint(1, 100)

print("Guess a number between 1 and 3.")
guess = int(input())

count = 0

while guess != answer:
    if guess < answer:
        print("Pick a higher number.")
        count += 1
    elif guess > answer:
        print("Pick a lower number.")
        count += 1
    elif guess == answer:
        print("You got it!")
print("It took you " + str(count) + " tries.")
```

Comment: You never update the guess within the loop. Instead of `print("Pick a higher number.")`, use `guess = int(input("Pick a higher number."))` and similar for the other cases.

Comment: Also, your answer could be anumber from 1 to 100, to have numbers from 1 to 3 do `answer = randint(1, 3)`

Comment: A `break` statement would be helpful. But please format your question properly, so that others can read it easily.

Comment: @Shravil You mean the code formatting? It's been fixed now, eh?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 3."))
    if guess < answer:
        print("Pick a higher number.")
        count += 1
    elif guess > answer:
        print("Pick a lower number.")
        count += 1
    elif guess == answer:
        print("You got it!")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me phrase it this way: When do you obtain the input from the user? What happens on a second loop run? Is `guess` at any time updated?

The answers to these (suggestive) questions will lead you to the right path:

You have to request input from the user in every loop run.

This will lead you to the point about how to start the loop.

```
from random import randint

answer = randint(1, 100)

count = 0
keep_loop = True

prompt = "Guess a number between 1 and 3."
while keep_loop:
    print(prompt)
    guess = int(input())
    if guess < answer:
        prompt = "Pick a higher number."
        count += 1
    elif guess > answer:
        prompt = "Pick a lower number."
        count += 1
    elif guess == answer:
        print("You got it!")
        keep_loop = False
print("It took you " + str(count) + " tries.")
```

Comment: IMHO, using a state variable isn't needed when you could just `break` out of a `while True` loop

Comment: @wjandrea You are right, but it depends on if you like `break` or not. Of couse, `break` would work as well.